# Bootstrap’s cards. How to shorten the words in card with ... . Django & CSS

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am using the Bootstrap's card to display my journals. It looks like this:

[Journal List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFqD9.png)

However, when I insert a lot of word, the card size will be veryyyy long.

[Journal List With really long essay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSWu1.png)

How to make it when there are long essays, it will shown like this:

Today is a good day. I started my day with coding. However, I found out that I **...**

Make it like "..."

This is the html code:

```html
<div class = "container mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="center_journal">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                {% for journal in journals %}
                <div class="card d-flex flex-column col-4 " style="width: 36rem;">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-4"><a href="{% url 'journal_detail' journal.id %}" >{{ journal.title }}</a></h5>
                    {% if journal.photo %}
                    <img src="{{ journal.photo.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {% if journal.audio %}
                        <audio controls>
                            <source src="{{ journal.audio.url }}" type="audio/ogg">
                            <source src="{{ journal.audio.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
                            <source src="{{ journal.audio.url }}" type="audio/wav">
                            Your browser does not support the audio element.
                        </audio>
                        {% endif %}
                        <p class="card-content text-center">{{ journal.content }}</p>
                        <p class="text-center font-weight-light">Created on {{ journal.date_created|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}</p>
                        {% if journal.favourite %}
                        <div class="text-center font-weight-light">
                            <p>Added to Favourite!</p>
                        </div>
                        {% endif%}
                        <!-- <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="{% url 'journal_detail' journal.id %}" ><button class=" btn btn-outline-info">View</button></a>
                        </div> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SOLVED!**
{{ journal.content | truncatewords:10}}

The result would be:

[image: Solution!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can truncate the lengths of the text with a Django template filter.
With [truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) you are able to set a maximum word count. Django will add an ellipsis if the text is longer and cut it at that word:

```
{{ value|truncatewords:2 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap v5.0 there is a classname for truncating text `text-truncate` ([docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/text-truncation/))

Or if you don't bother adding a custom style, you could use `-webkit-line-clamp` property as below

```
.card-text {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

This will truncate a text with more than 2 lines in length.

Comment: @T R A C E ツ I am using Bootstrap v4.0.

Comment: @T R A C E ツ  Although the solution from @Marco is working, I still want to know that is it correct to change `.card-text` to `.card-context.text-center` for my code? Because there is no changes when I apply the code you provide.

Comment: You can give it a try since it is intended for the cards content (in your case .card-context.text-center)

Comment: It's not working. BTW thanks for responding!

Comment: Yep it's not working because you have .card-content.text-center not .card-context